# how can i speed up video processing : python

Tags: python, video, image-processing, video-streaming

```
import time
import picamera
import picamera.array
import numpy as np
import cv2

clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit= 8, tileGridSize=(4,4))

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
with picamera.array.PiRGBArray(camera) as stream:
    camera.resolution = (320,240)

    while True:
        camera.capture(stream,'bgr',use_video_port=True)
        med1 = cv2.medianBlur(stream.array,5)
        med3 =clahe.apply(med1)
        img1=med3
        height, width = med3.shape
        for i in range(0,height):
            for j in range(0,width):
                if ((img1[i, j] >= [75,75,75]).all() and (img1[i, j] <[110,110,110]).all()):
                    med3[i,j]= med3[i,j]-8
                elif((img1[i, j] >= [125,125,125]).all() and (img1[i, [140,140,140]).all()):
                    med3[i,j]= med3[i,j]+2
        cv2.imshow('img.jpg',med3)
        cv2.waitKey(100)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('a'):
            cv2.imwrite('2015_01_05_43.jpg',med2)
            cv2.imwrite('2015_01_05_44.jpg',med3)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        stream.seek(0)
        stream.truncate()
```

i was trying to manipulate some pixels in the video for each frame. The process is working. But the output is too slow. I know this is happening because it has to scan all the pixels for every frame. Can anyone help in doing the same process in a faster way. Is there any other solution to solve the issue.

Comment: 1. Try overclocking the Pi; 2. Try reading/opening the camera stream using OpenCv instead of picamera 3. See if you can replace the nested `for` loop with a pre-build, optimized numpy (for e.g.) matrix operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your first choice should be using the fact its a numpy array and use numpy's slicing and broadcasting abilities instead of iterating through the pixels. This will do essentially the same but in numpy's c code level which is optimized for these things.
For example the loops with the first condition could be replaced with just:

```
img1[(img1 >= [75,75,75]) & (img1 <= [110,110,110])] -= 8
```

Comment: this line seems to be great. but when i use ,it is hitting error "operands could not be broadcast togather with the shapes [240,320] (3).

Comment: I cant know for sure without debugging this myself with the actual object. But basically it complains about the structure of img1 (its shape) and the structure of [75,75,75]. You can try for example comparing it just to 75 and 110. For other options read more about numpy broadcasting.